# Hidden textbox loose its value while submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've a form with fields and **RequiredFieldValidator**. Below, I've have another textbox, hidden, which I valorize with a js function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (sender, args) {
    $("#myTextField").val("HELLO");
});
</script>
```

When I submit the form, if I forgot to fill the required value, the textbox "myTextField" loose it's value and I'm not be able to fill it again. How can I trigger the submit event and fill the hidden field anyway?

Comment: can you show the full code (html/js) and/or create a jsfiddle

Comment: For the hidden textbox you using display: none or visible="false"?

Comment: Nicholas, I use display:none

Comment: JQuery setting hidden textbox for the required field must be do on page load ?

Comment: Well no, I've placed on pageLoad because sometimes the required field are valorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure is this what you want... But here this is my code....

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="hide"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="txt is required" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:TextBox ID="test" runat="server" Text="" onkeyup="rewriteText(this)"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="submit" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txt').val("Lol");
    });

    function rewriteText(txt) {
        $('#txt').val(txt.value);
    }
</script>
```

The jquery will write "Lol" to the require textbox.
So you can submit it...
If you want to delete it and submit then u just press backspace in the textbox then the value will be empty.

PS: I just mock up without proper testing...

Hope this help you